# Multiple one to many conditions returns null

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I make SQL query with multiple related conditions. But it returns null on result.

```sql
SELECT "Directory"."parentId", "Directory"."objectClass", "Directory"."whenCreated", "Directory"."whenChanged", "Directory".id, "Directory".name, "Directory".depth, "Users_1"."sAMAccountName", "Users_1"."userPrincipalName", "Users_1"."displayName", "Users_1"."directoryId", "Users_1".id 
AS id_1, "Users_1".mail, "Users_1".password 
FROM "Directory" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Users" ON "Directory".id = "Users"."directoryId" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Attributes" ON "Directory".id = "Attributes"."directoryId" 
JOIN "Paths" ON "Directory".id = "Paths".endpoint_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Users" AS "Users_1" ON "Directory".id = "Users_1"."directoryId" 
WHERE 
    lower("Attributes".name) = 'objectclass' AND lower("Attributes".value) = 'posixaccount' AND 
    lower("Attributes".name) = 'uid' AND lower("Attributes".value) = 'username3'
```

When I change query to 1 pair of conditions, it returns what it should:

```sql
WHERE
    lower("Attributes".name) = 'uid' AND lower("Attributes".value) = 'username3'
```

(returns username3 row)

```sql
WHERE 
    lower("Attributes".name) = 'objectclass' AND lower("Attributes".value) = 'posixaccount'
```

(returns all usernames 0-5)

I can't perform join with condition, due to random conditions quantity.

How to make this query return rows?

P.S. I make this query with SQLAlchemy

Comment: sorry, but in you where condition you have lower("Attributes".name) = 'objectclass' AND lower("Attributes".name) = 'uid'  It looks strange

Comment: @Sergey just case-insensetive query, nothing changes if I remove `lower` function and add proper case to text

Comment: Your WHERE clause is saying that lower("Attributes".name) = 'objectclass' and lower("Attributes".name) = 'uid' - at the same time. Obviously the same field on the same record cannot have two different values, which is why your query returns no results. You probably need to separate the two lines with an OR rather than an AND and put brackets round them to ensure the correct precedence

Comment: @NickW Yeah, I already got it, looks like I need to rewrite query with joins' conditions: 
`left join attributes a1 on a1.directoryid = directory.id and a1.name = 'objectclass' left join attributes a2 on a2.directoryid = directory.id and a2.name = 'uid'`